# Search a string array for a specific string.

Tags: java, linear-search

I was hoping someone could help. Well I know how to use linear search to find a numerical value inside of an array. But now I want to learn how to search a string array for a string.

For example if I have a string array of students names how could I search the array to find a specific name inside that array?

If someone could write me a simple example since I'm new to Java still. Thank you, also is there a better way to search these kinds of things or linear search fine? :)

Comment: When you say "help" but show no effort, people interpret that as "do it for me" which is why you're getting downvoted. "write me a simple example" probably didn't help either. Please make some effort before asking next time as this is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Arrays.asList()` to wrap the array in a List. Then search in the List using `contains()` method:

```
String[] a= {"is", "are", "then"};
Arrays.asList(a).contains("are");
```

You can do using arrays also, but have to write some more lines of code. `contains()` method also does the `linear` search only.

```
public static boolean useLoop(String[] arr, String targetValue) {
    for(String s: arr){
        if(s.equals(targetValue))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for Strings can be the same as for numerical values, except you should use the String class's `equals(...)` method instead of `==`.

You should use `equals(...)` because it's possible for two different String objects to have the same characters. But `==` would be incorrect because they are different objects.

Examples comparison expressions:

```
myArray[i].equals(myString)
```

or

```
myString.equals(myArray[i])
```

Note: Be sure the part on the left side isn't `null`. Otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`.